# I'm making a collapsing toolbar in android with custom view.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

The collapse functioning of the toolbar is working well but the effect is very bad and it jitters while expanding and collapsing. Below is my layout code. Even sometimes the toolbar becomes quite big. I have used a custom view instead of an image in this code. The custom view is constraint Layout. The particular code inside a fragment and the fragment consists of tab layout that has a recyclerview in it. I have used parallax effect for the custom view so I am not quite sure about it.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        tools:context=".ProfileFragment"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--this is the collapse mode-->
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="1dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="304dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/colorAccent"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
                app:title="paco">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    >


                    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
                        android:layout_width="87dp"
                        android:layout_height="87dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:contentDescription="Profile Image"
                        android:src="@drawable/capture"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/editImage"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                        android:contentDescription="TODO"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profileImage"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profileImage"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_launch_24px" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/artistName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:text="Paco Pardesi"
                        android:textColor="#333333"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profileImage"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profileImage"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileImage" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/country"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:text="India"
                        android:textColor="#757575"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/artistName"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/artistName"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/artistName" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/descriptionArtist"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="Artist from the paradise on earth, Kashmir. I like to create art that is about freedom and fresh thinking."
                        android:textColor="#323232"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/country" />

                    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textviewLayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descriptionArtist">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/uploadCount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="1233"
                            android:textColor="#bea57c"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Uploads"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Uploads"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Uploads"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                            android:text="Uploads"
                            android:textColor="#333333"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uploadCount" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/createdCount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="4567"
                            android:textColor="#bea57c"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/created"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/created"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/created"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                            android:text="Created"
                            android:textColor="#333333"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Uploads"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createdCount" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/likesCount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="8000"
                            android:textColor="#bea57c"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/likes"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/likes"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/likes"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                            android:text="Likes"
                            android:textColor="#333333"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                           app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/created"
                       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/likesCount" />

                    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:alpha="0"
                    android:background="@android:color/black"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/result_tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/colorNormal"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="#f6f6f6"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabTextColor="#333333" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all custom components which are currently present inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` into a separate layout file. Then use
`<include layout="@layout/my_custom_layout"/>`.

Don't know why but works for me somehow. See if this works for you.